# how to receive a take with runSaga / redux-saga

Tags: testing, jasmine, mocking, jestjs, redux-saga

I created a `recordSaga` function, its target is to record what actions have been dispatched during the saga.

```js
export const recordSaga = async (saga, initialAction, state) => {
  const dispatched = [];

  const done = await runSaga(
    {
      dispatch: action => dispatched.push(action),
      getState: () => state,
    },
    saga,
    initialAction,
  ).done;

  return {
    dispatched,
    done,
  };
};
```

so let's say my saga is this one

```js
export function* mySaga() {
  const needToSave = yield select(needToSaveDocument);
  if (needToSave) {
    yield put(saveDocument());
    yield take(SAVE_DOCUMENT_SUCCESS);
  }
  yield put(doSomethingElse())
}
```

I want to write two tests, which I expect to be the following

```js
describe('mySaga', async () => {
  it('test 1: no need to save', async () => {    
    const state = { needToSave: false }
    const { dispatched } = await recordSaga(mySaga, {}, state);
    expect(dispatched).toEqual([
      doSomethingElse()
    ])
  })
  it('test 2: need to save', async () => {
    const state = { needToSave: true }
    const { dispatched } = await recordSaga(mySaga, {}, state);
    expect(dispatched).toEqual([
      saveDocument(),
      doSomethingElse()
    ])
  })
})
```

However, for the test 2 where there is a `take` in between, and of course `jest` (or its girlfriend `jasmine`) is yelling at me: `Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.`

I know it is because `runSaga` is waiting for the `take(SAVE_DOCUMENT_SUCCESS)`, but how can I mock that up ?

Answer (score 2):

## The answer `stdChannel().put({type, payload})`

### Why ?

Using `stdChannel` you can dispatch after the first run.

### How ?

- import stdChannel;
- add to the first param in runSaga;
- call `stdChannel().put(SAVE_DOCUMENT_SUCCESS)`;

### Example

#### what worked for me

I left the first test as it is the expected final result, but the solution comes on the last 2.

```js
  import { runSaga, stdchannel } from 'redux-saga'
  let dispatchedActions = [];
  let channel;
  let fakeStore;

  beforeEach(() => {
    channel = stdChannel(); // you have to declare the channel to have access to it later
    fakeStore = {
      channel, // add it to the store in runSaga
      getState: () => "initial",
      dispatch: (action) => dispatchedActions.push(action),
    };
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    global.fetch.mockClear();
  });

 it("executes getData correctly", async () => {
    await runSaga(fakeStore, getData, getAsyncData("test")).toPromise();
    expect(global.fetch.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1);
    expect(dispatchedActions[0]).toEqual(setData(set_value));
  });

  it("triggers takeLatest and call getData(), but unfortunately doesn't resolve promise", async () => {
    await runSaga(fakeStore, rootSaga)// .toPromise() cannot be used here, as will throw Timeout error
    channel.put(getAsyncData("test")); // if remove this line, the next 2 expects() will fail
    expect(global.fetch.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1);
    // expect(dispatchedActions[1]).toEqual(setData(set_value)); // will fail here, but pass on the next it()
  });

  it("takes the promised data from test above", () => {
    expect(dispatchedActions[1]).toEqual(setData(set_value));
  });
```

[this answer (about true code, not tests) helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60569822/12669100)

Answer (score 0):

By looking at `recordSaga`:

```
export const recordSaga = async (saga, initialAction, state) => {
```

It seems that you should pass `{type: SAVE_DOCUMENT_SUCCESS}` as a second argument (i.e `initialAction`). That should trigger the `take` effect.

Comment: well it is not the `initialAction`, so it does not work for me. I tried your solution but the same mistake appears