# How to start a redux saga watcher using runSaga

Tags: reactjs, redux, generator, redux-saga

I am not able to figure out from the documentation how to start a redux saga watcher using runSaga. Suppose I have the following in `saga.js`:

```
export function* fetchJokeSaga(action) {
  try {
    const response = yield call(axios.get, "...");
    yield put({ type: "UPDATE_JOKE", payload: response });
  } catch (e) {}
}

export default function* watcherSaga(action) {
  yield takeEvery("FETCH_JOKE", fetchJokeSaga);
}
```

and the following in `Component.js`:

```
const Component = () => {
  const store = useStore();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { joke } = useSelector(state => state);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    runSaga({ dispatch, getState: store.getState }, watcherSaga);
  }, []);

  return joke;
};
```

I'm not able to trigger the api call using `dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_JOKE' })`.
But when I use `fetchJokeSaga` directly as `runSaga({ dispatch, getState: store.getState }, fetchJokeSaga);`, it makes the api call immediately.
How do I dynamically start `watcherSaga` so that I can dispatch 'FETCH_JOKES' later?

Comment: https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/1724

Answer (score 1):

azundo almost had the solution. You need to '**put**' some actions in the channel to get the generator started.

```
import {stdChannel, runSaga} from 'redux-saga';

const Component = () => {
   const store = useStore();
   const dispatch = useDispatch();
   const { joke } = useSelector(state => state);

   React.useEffect(() => {
       const channel = stdChannel();
       runSaga({ dispatch, getState: store.getState, channel}, watcherSaga);
       channel.put({ type: 'FETCH_JOKE' });
   }, []);

   return joke;
};
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `watcher` saga is using the `take` effect it needs a `channel` to listen on. Unless you're doing something custom you'll want the normal `stdChannel` that `redux-saga` provides:

```
import {stdChannel, runSaga} from 'redux-saga';

const Component = () => {
  const store = useStore();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { joke } = useSelector(state => state);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    runSaga({ dispatch, getState: store.getState, channel: stdChannel()}, watcherSaga);
  }, []);

  return joke;
};
```

Comment: I tried using a channel. But no luck. I see my actions being dispatched but the watcher is not waking up to make the api call.

Comment: As mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60569822/6324591 we need to call `put` on the channel to trigger the watcher :)